# Laravel how to get data from controller to event listener?

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am working on to-do list page. I want to log all of task process to database like '**Walk**' "**completed.**" But i cannot get '**walk**' data to listener. It says "*Undefined property: App\Events\ToDoEditEvent::$message*" (In here $message means To-do task.) What should i do?

**Controller**

```
#Controller
public function arrangeTask($id)
{
    $task = ToDoTask::find($id);
    if ($task->completedTask == false){
        $task->completedTask = true;
    }
    else{
        $task->completedTask = false;
    }

    $event = new UserLog();
    $event->message = $task->TaskName;
    event(new ToDoEditEvent($event));

    $task->save();
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

**Event**

```
#EditEvent
class ToDoEditEvent
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

public $userLog;
/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(UserLog $userLog)
{
    $this->userLog = $userLog;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
}
}
```

**Listener (Already configure EventServiceProvider staff)**

```
class ToDoEditListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  ToDoEditEvent  $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(ToDoEditEvent $event)
{
    $currentTimestamp = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    $addTask = DB::table('user_logs')->insert([
            'message'=>$event->message,
            'context'=>'Düzenleme',
            'extra'=>Auth::user()->name,
            'created_at'=>$currentTimestamp,
            'updated_at'=>$currentTimestamp
        ]
    );
    return $addTask;
}
}
```

**UserLog Model**

```
class UserLog extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        "message" => ToDoCreatedEvent::class
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct(UserLog $userLog)
{
    $this->userLog = $userLog;
}
```

instead of using

```
public function __construct(ToDoTask $userLog)
{
    $this->userLog = $userLog;
}
```

Which means if you use task class instead of event, it works.
And also;

```
#Controller
public function arrangeTask($id)
{
    $task = ToDoTask::find($id);
    if ($task->completedTask == false){
        $task->completedTask = true;
    }
    else{
        $task->completedTask = false;
    }

    $event = new UserLog();
    $event->message = $task->TaskName;
    event(new ToDoEditEvent($event));

    $task->save();
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

If you use below instead of up you can reach all of variables in the task staff.

```
#Controller
    public function arrangeTask($id)
    {
        $task = ToDoTask::find($id);
        if ($task->completedTask == false){
            $task->completedTask = true;
        }
        else{
            $task->completedTask = false;
        }
        event(new ToDoEditEvent($task));
        $task->save();
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```